# I tried to implement the RSA encryption algorithm using cpp, but it takes too long and I don't know if it will work

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, cryptography

My code is here

```
//RSA.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "BigNum.hpp"
using namespace std;

BigNum mygcd(BigNum a, BigNum b)
{
    while(a != b)
    {
        if(a>b)
        {
            a = a - b;
        }
        else 
        {
            b = b - a;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
BigNum prime(int n)
{
    vector<BigNum> ans;
    ans.push_back(BigNum(2));
    ans.push_back(BigNum(3));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        BigNum addend = 1;
        for (auto j : ans)
        {
            addend = addend * j;
        }
        ans.push_back(addend + 1);
    }
    return ans[ans.size() - 1];
}
BigNum exgcd(BigNum a, BigNum b, BigNum &x, BigNum &y)
{
    if (b == 0)
    {
        x = 1, y = 0;
        return a;
    }
    BigNum g = exgcd(b, a - (a / b) * b, x, y);
    BigNum t;
    t = x;
    x = y;
    y = t - a / b * y;
    return g;
}
BigNum niyuan(BigNum a, BigNum b)
{
    BigNum x, y;
    BigNum aa = exgcd(a, b, x, y);
    return (x + b) - ((x + b) / b) * b;
}
vector<BigNum> yinshu(BigNum n)
{
    vector<BigNum> ans;
    int a = 2;
    while (n / 2 > a)
    {
        if (n % a == 0)
        {
            ans.push_back(a);
        }
        a++;
    }
    return ans;
}
vector<int> ToBit(BigNum obj){
    vector<int> r;
    while (obj != 0){
        r.push_back( (obj - (obj / 2) * 2 == 0) ? 0 : 1 );
        obj = obj / 2;
    }
    return r;
}
BigNum jiami(BigNum e, int i, BigNum n)
{
    BigNum addend = i;
    BigNum result = 1;
    vector<int>bitE = ToBit(e);
    int now = 0;
    while (now != bitE.size())
    { 
        if (bitE[now])
        {
            result = addend * result;
            result = result - (result / n) * n;
        }
        addend = addend * addend;
        now = now + 1;
    }
    return result;
}
BigNum jiemi(BigNum d, BigNum i, BigNum n)
{
    BigNum addend = i;
    BigNum result = 1;
    vector<int>bitD = ToBit(d);
    int now = 0;
    while (now != bitD.size())
    {
        if (bitD[now])
        {
            result = addend * result;
            result = result - (result / n) * n;
        }
        addend = addend * addend;
        now = now + 1;
    }
    return result;
}
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    BigNum p = prime(rand() % 20 + 1); 
    srand(time(0));
    BigNum q = prime(rand() % 20 + 1); 
    BigNum N = p * q;                  
    BigNum r = (p - 1) * (q - 1);      
sss:
    srand(time(0));
    BigNum e = random() + 2;
    if (mygcd(e, r) - BigNum(1) > 0)
        goto sss;
    vector<BigNum> yinshus = yinshu(r);                        
    BigNum d = BigNum(niyuan(e, r));                             
    cout << "Alice send(" << N << ',' << e << ")to Bob" << endl; 
    cout << "Please input your massage:";                        
    string m;
    cin >> m; 
    vector<int> message;
    for (auto i : m)
    {
        message.push_back((int)i);
    }
    vector<BigNum> miwen;
    for (auto i : message)
    {
        miwen.push_back(jiami(e, i, N));
    }
    cout << "coded text：";
    for (auto i : miwen)
    {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    vector<BigNum> minwen;
    for (auto i : miwen)
    {
        minwen.push_back(jiemi(d, i, N));
    }
    cout << "明文：";
    for (auto i : minwen)
    {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

I used a self-defined data structure called BigNum in order to store some large integers without them overflowing.

```
//BigNum.hpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

#define MAXN 9999
#define MAXSIZE 10
#define DLEN 4

class BigNum
{
private:
    int a[999]; 
    int len;    
public:
    BigNum()
    {
        len = 1;
        memset(a, 0, sizeof(a));
    }                                  
    BigNum(const int);                 
    BigNum(const char *);              
    BigNum(const BigNum &);            
    BigNum &operator=(const BigNum &); 

    friend istream &operator>>(istream &, BigNum &); 
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &, BigNum &); 

    BigNum operator+(const BigNum &) const;
    BigNum operator-(const BigNum &) const; 
    BigNum operator*(const BigNum &) const; 
    BigNum operator/(const int &) const;    
    BigNum operator/(const BigNum &) const;

    BigNum operator^(const int &) const;   
    int operator%(const int &) const;      
    bool operator>(const BigNum &T) const; 
    bool operator>(const int &t) const;    

    bool operator<(const BigNum &) const;
    bool operator<=(const BigNum &) const;
    bool operator>=(const BigNum &) const;
    bool operator==(const BigNum &) const;
    bool operator!=(const BigNum &) const;

    void print(); 
};
BigNum::BigNum(const int b) 
{
    int c, d = b;
    len = 0;
    memset(a, 0, sizeof(a));
    while (d > MAXN)
    {
        c = d - (d / (MAXN + 1)) * (MAXN + 1);
        d = d / (MAXN + 1);
        a[len++] = c;
    }
    a[len++] = d;
}
BigNum::BigNum(const char *s)
{
    int t, k, index, l, i;
    memset(a, 0, sizeof(a));
    l = strlen(s);
    len = l / DLEN;
    if (l % DLEN)
        len++;
    index = 0;
    for (i = l - 1; i >= 0; i -= DLEN)
    {
        t = 0;
        k = i - DLEN + 1;
        if (k < 0)
            k = 0;
        for (int j = k; j <= i; j++)
            t = t * 10 + s[j] - '0';
        a[index++] = t;
    }
}
BigNum::BigNum(const BigNum &T) : len(T.len) 
{
    int i;
    memset(a, 0, sizeof(a));
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        a[i] = T.a[i];
}
BigNum &BigNum::operator=(const BigNum &n)
{
    int i;
    len = n.len;
    memset(a, 0, sizeof(a));
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        a[i] = n.a[i];
    return *this;
}
istream &operator>>(istream &in, BigNum &b) 
{
    char ch[MAXSIZE * 4];
    int i = -1;
    in >> ch;
    int l = strlen(ch);
    int count = 0, sum = 0;
    for (i = l - 1; i >= 0;)
    {
        sum = 0;
        int t = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4 && i >= 0; j++, i--, t *= 10)
        {
            sum += (ch[i] - '0') * t;
        }
        b.a[count] = sum;
        count++;
    }
    b.len = count++;
    return in;
}
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, BigNum &b) 
{
    int i;
    cout << b.a[b.len - 1];
    for (i = b.len - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout.width(DLEN);
        cout.fill('0');
        cout << b.a[i];
    }
    return out;
}

BigNum BigNum::operator+(const BigNum &T) const 
{
    BigNum t(*this);
    int i, big;
    big = T.len > len ? T.len : len;
    for (i = 0; i < big; i++)
    {
        t.a[i] += T.a[i];
        if (t.a[i] > MAXN)
        {
            t.a[i + 1]++;
            t.a[i] -= MAXN + 1;
        }
    }
    if (t.a[big] != 0)
        t.len = big + 1;
    else
        t.len = big;
    return t;
}
BigNum BigNum::operator-(const BigNum &T) const 
{
    int i, j, big;
    bool flag;
    BigNum t1, t2;
    if (*this > T)
    {
        t1 = *this;
        t2 = T;
        flag = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        t1 = T;
        t2 = *this;
        flag = 1;
    }
    big = t1.len;
    for (i = 0; i < big; i++)
    {
        if (t1.a[i] < t2.a[i])
        {
            j = i + 1;
            while (t1.a[j] == 0)
                j++;
            t1.a[j--]--;
            while (j > i)
                t1.a[j--] += MAXN;
            t1.a[i] += MAXN + 1 - t2.a[i];
        }
        else
            t1.a[i] -= t2.a[i];
    }
    t1.len = big;
    while (t1.a[t1.len - 1] == 0 && t1.len > 1)
    {
        t1.len--;
        big--;
    }
    if (flag)
        t1.a[big - 1] = 0 - t1.a[big - 1];
    return t1;
}

BigNum BigNum::operator*(const BigNum &T) const 
{
    BigNum ret;
    int i, j, up;
    int temp, temp1;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        up = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < T.len; j++)
        {
            temp = a[i] * T.a[j] + ret.a[i + j] + up;
            if (temp > MAXN)
            {
                temp1 = temp - temp / (MAXN + 1) * (MAXN + 1);
                up = temp / (MAXN + 1);
                ret.a[i + j] = temp1;
            }
            else
            {
                up = 0;
                ret.a[i + j] = temp;
            }
        }
        if (up != 0)
            ret.a[i + j] = up;
    }
    ret.len = i + j;
    while (ret.a[ret.len - 1] == 0 && ret.len > 1)
        ret.len--;
    return ret;
}
BigNum BigNum::operator/(const int &b) const 
{
    BigNum ret;
    int i, down = 0;
    for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        ret.a[i] = (a[i] + down * (MAXN + 1)) / b;
        down = a[i] + down * (MAXN + 1) - ret.a[i] * b;
    }
    ret.len = len;
    while (ret.a[ret.len - 1] == 0 && ret.len > 1)
        ret.len--;
    return ret;
}
int BigNum::operator%(const int &b) const 
{
    int i, d = 0;
    for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        d = ((d * (MAXN + 1)) % b + a[i]) % b;
    }
    return d;
}
BigNum BigNum::operator^(const int &n) const 
{
    BigNum t, ret(1);
    int i;
    if (n < 0)
        exit(-1);
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    if (n == 1)
        return *this;
    int m = n;
    while (m > 1)
    {
        t = *this;
        for (i = 1; i << 1 <= m; i <<= 1)
        {
            t = t * t;
        }
        m -= i;
        ret = ret * t;
        if (m == 1)
            ret = ret * (*this);
    }
    return ret;
}
bool BigNum::operator>(const BigNum &T) const
{
    int ln;
    if (len > T.len)
        return true;
    else if (len == T.len)
    {
        ln = len - 1;
        while (a[ln] == T.a[ln] && ln >= 0)
            ln--;
        if (ln >= 0 && a[ln] > T.a[ln])
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
bool BigNum::operator>(const int &t) const 
{
    BigNum b(t);
    return *this > b;
}

void BigNum::print() 
{
    int i;
    cout << a[len - 1];
    for (i = len - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout.width(DLEN);
        cout.fill('0');
        cout << a[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

bool BigNum::operator<(const BigNum &obj) const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] < obj.a[i])
            return true;
        if (a[i] > obj.a[i])
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}
bool BigNum::operator<=(const BigNum &obj) const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] < obj.a[i])
            return true;
        if (a[i] > obj.a[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
bool BigNum::operator>=(const BigNum &obj) const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] > obj.a[i])
            return true;
        if (a[i] < obj.a[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
bool BigNum::operator==(const BigNum &obj) const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != obj.a[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
bool BigNum::operator!=(const BigNum &obj) const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != obj.a[i])
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
BigNum BigNum::operator/(const BigNum &op2) const
{
    BigNum temp(*this);
    if (op2 == 0)
    {
        cout << "ERROR!!";
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            temp.a[i] = 0;
    }
    else if (*this < op2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            temp.a[i] = 0;
    }
    else if (*this == op2)
    {
        temp.a[len - 1] = 1;
    }
    else if (op2 == 1)
    {
        temp = *this;
    }
    else if (op2 == 2)
    {

        int from = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (temp.a[i] != 0)
            {
                from = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        int carry = 0;
        for (int i = from; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (temp.a[i] & 1)
            {
                if (carry == 1)
                    temp.a[i] = (temp.a[i] + 10) / 2;
                else
                    temp.a[i] = temp.a[i] / 2;
                carry = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (carry == 1)
                    temp.a[i] = (temp.a[i] + 10) / 2;
                else
                    temp.a[i] = temp.a[i] / 2;
                carry = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        BigNum begin(1), end("500000000000000000000000000000"); // 500000000000000000000000000000
        while (begin < end)
        {
            BigNum mid = (begin + end) / 2;
            BigNum res = mid * op2;

            if (res == 0 || res >= *this)
                end = mid;
            else
                begin = mid + 1;
        }
        temp = begin;
        if (temp == 1)
            return 0;

        int tmp = len - 1;
        while (temp.a[tmp] == 0)
        {
            temp.a[tmp] = 9;
            tmp++;
        }
        temp.a[tmp]--;
        return temp;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

When I run it, sometimes I get the error "malloc(): corrupted top size", sometimes it will run and then nothing happens, when I debug it, I find that the problem is in the "mygcd" function, the algorithm I use is too slow for a huge The algorithm I'm using is too slow for the huge number, but I don't know how to change it. I'm not sure where in the two files something is going wrong that I don't know about, and I can't guarantee that all the algorithms I'm using are correct and appropriate. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.
My system is Ubuntu 22.04.1LTS
gcc version 11.2.0
Now I deleted all the Chinese comments

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm - there should be several C++ implementations available via a quick google search

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings and pay attention to them. Use AddressSanitizer. With just a little bit of your `main` you have a lot to fix. https://godbolt.org/z/r64GoxPTT Seeing `srand(time(0));` three times and a goto that could be an endless loop aren't good signs.

Comment: *I tried to implement the RSA encryption algorithm using cpp, but it takes too long and I don't know if it will work* -- Is this for fun, or for an actual program you're developing that you plan on distributing?  If it's an actual program, I suggest you not do this, and instead use an already existing library that has implemented RSA encryption.  Just the mere fact that you are getting this wrong is an indication that you shouldn't try to do this.  If there are any bugs in your implementation, then that's a big hole in the encryption that can be exploited.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This is only for fun

Comment: @xxxxxxxb -- Well, the first thing you really should do is *remove* code.  The code to remove would be `BigNum::operator=` and the `BigNum` copy constructor.  Why should they be removed?  Because your `BigNum` class has member variables that will already be copied safely by the compiler's default version of these functions.  By you stepping in and overriding the compiler's default version, you are risking creating bugs.  The less code you write, the less chance bugs will happen.

Comment: @xxxxxxxb -- The next thing after that is to rewrite your `BigNum` relational operators to use `==` and `<`, and not recreate the same code over and over again.  The only two functions that you need to implement fully are `<` and `==`, and all the others can be written in terms of those two operators.  For example, `operator !=` is simply `return !(*this == obj);`, `operator>` is `return (obj < *this);`, etc.  The reason why you should do this is because, again, less chance of bugs, and the other relational operators will just work correctly.

Comment: Also, remove `using namespace std;` from RSA.hpp.  Do not do this in header files.  Also, please remove the comments from the posted code.  Others who may want to compile the code may have an encoding issue with the Chinese characters being part of the source text.  Also, `friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, BigNum &);` should have the last argument as a const reference: `friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const BigNum &);`

Comment: Look into [GNU GMP](https://gmplib.org/) for efficient bignum support. Also, remember to always use an optimized build of your software when benchmarking performance - debug builds (the default compilers create) can be *really* slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After applying all of the changes suggested in the comments:

1. Remove `using namespace std;`
2. Remove superfluous `BigNum::operator=` and `BigNum::BigNum(BigNum&)`
3. Only implement fully `BigNum::operator<` and `BigNum::operator==`, and the other relational operators are based on those two operators
4. Make `BigNum::operator <<` have the second argument as a const reference to `BigNum`.

the compiler [here](https://godbolt.org/z/8c58r6rz6) warns of `j` not being initialized.

```
BigNum BigNum::operator*(const BigNum &T) const //两个大数之间的相乘运算
{
    BigNum ret;
    int i, j, up;
    //...
    ret.len = i + j;
    //...
}
```

You see the results of the run, with the Address Sanitizer showing that things are not working right.

When `j` is initialized to 0, then the program [runs without error](https://godbolt.org/z/GP7zzdqEP), at least the `main` you provided runs without error.

---

Edit:

On further inspection, you are accessing `arr` out-of-bounds.  After changing the `a` to `std::array<int, 999> a;` and used `at()` within `BigNum::operator *`, a `std::out_of_range` exception is thrown:

[Here is the updated code](https://godbolt.org/z/oTsdchb15).

Also, please name your variables with meaningful names, not one letter names like `a`.  Naming your variables properly will aid in understanding the code a lot better.

Comment: But how should I define the modulo operation of BigNum? This is important to improve the mygcd function.

Comment: Your code had issues far beyond the modulo operator, and one of those issues is what was pointed out in the answer.  Either one of the issues (uninitialized `j` or accessing an array out-of-bounds) can cause the program to enter undefined behavior land, causing the code to seem slow.  But as a comment already suggest, if this is so important, use a class that has been already developed for "big integers".